# Does the usage of seperate scenes cut down on render time for an animation?

Tags: rendering, scene

I could have the different locations and objects of the shots all set up in the same scene and have the camera move to each shot.

I guess my question is whether the objects out of frame affect the render time?

Comment: Hello :). Yes they do affect it. All the objects still interact (cast shadows, reflections) and need to be calculated no matter if they're in/out of frame.

Comment: Alright thank you very much!